# How would I configure etherchannel for this particular topology?

Tags: cisco, switch, switching, packet-tracer, etherchannel

[image]

How would I setup and configure etherchannel from switch0 to all the other switches?
Switch0 has been configured as the root bridge, Router0 has been configured to be the gateway for each Vlan and as a dhcp server, and all the switches are properly connected (as access and trunk interfaces)

Comment: You need multiple connections from Switch0 to the other switches, but you are not showing that in the drawing.

Comment: What Ron said. What the exercise wants you to do is add dual connections to all other switches from Switch0 and configure them as portchannels.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since all "*education, certification, or homework*" questions are off-topic here, we will not give you the answer (and you don't include enough information for that, anyway), but below is enough information for you to figure out the answer for yourself.

On the distribution switch (Switch0), you need to create port channel interfaces to each access switch:

```
interface Portchannel<channel number>
```

Then place all the interface configurations in common for that channel to an access switch under the channel interface. After that, you add the physical interfaces to an access switch to the channel under the physical interface configuration. It depends on the particular channel protocol you want to use.

Unconditionally channel:

```
channel-group <channel number> mode on
```

PAgP:

```
channel-group <channel number> mode desirable
```

LACP

```
channel-group <channel number> mode active
```

You then do the same thing on the access switches for the interfaces back to the distribution switch.

The distribution switch will have one channel interface for each access switch, and each access switch will have one channel interface back to the distribution switch.